# Argument restrict_vocab from Gensim KeyedVector most_similar not working as expected

Tags: python, gensim, word-embedding

I am using the Gensim KeyedVector most_similar function to find the top N word vectors similar to a subset of other word vectors. My model vocabulary is such that the top X are the word vectors I would like to *search through and return*, and indices X+1 and greater contain the words that I am searching *with*. I.e., when I search, I would not like to search through anything beyond index X.

I am using the restrict_vocab=X flag to only search through the top X of the vocab. I noticed that some of the nearest neighbors that are being returned are NOT from the top X and was wondering if anyone had any insights into what is going on here?

Specifically, I am using a version with an annoy indexer and a version without:

```
neighbors = word_vec_model.most_similar(positive=[root_word], topn=N, restrict_vocab=X)
```

and

```
neighbors = word_vec_model.most_similar(positive=[root_word], topn=N, restrict_vocab=X, indexer=annoy_index)
```

I verified that a word vector that is being returned is greater than X by getting the index in the vocab:

```
list(word_vec_model.vocab.keys()).index(returned_neighbor)
```

and saw that it was a number greater than X.

EDIT:

```
print(word_vec_model.vocab[returned_neighbor].index)
```

returned the same number as above.

I created my word_vec_model with the following line of code:

```
word_vec_model = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('embeddings.txt', binary=False)
```

where each line in the file is a keyword and a 512 dimensional vector. The file is formatted such that the first X are my *search through* words, and the X+1 and greater lines are the *search with* words. I expected the words to be read in in order and the .vocab attribute confirms this.

Comment: Note that your method of returning the word's index won't necessarily return its actual position. As it looks like you're using a pre-4.0.0 version of Gensim (from the presence of the `.vocab` dict), a better way to check a word's position is with `print(word_vec_model.vocab[returned_neighbor].index)`. Does that still return a number larger than your `restrict_vocab` argument? If so, can you say more about how `word_vec_model` was loaded or created? Also, what happens if you use a tiny `restrict_vocab=5`, with a `topn=10 ` – do you get 5 or 10 results?

Comment: @gojomo thanks for the response! I have added details about how I loaded the embeddings into the model and the ordering of such. As per your last question, if I do restrict_vocab=5 and topn=10, I get 5 (actually 4 as it does not return itself as part of the 5) results... so it seems to be working here perfectly.

Comment: @gojomo Actually, your response helped a TON in debugging!! It was the version with the annoy indexer that caused restrict_vocab to be ignored. This is unfortunate, but glad I was able to figure it out. Thanks again

Comment: That sounds like a bug specific to that mode with the external index - please consider filing a bug report at: https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/issues